linux mint mate display setting
Installing linux mint mate 21.3 on a desktop 500GB SSD.
Display settings after install are not the same display settings from usb flash drive. Mint display settings prior to installation can be set to 1920x1080 @60Hz.
How can I get the prior installation display settings after installed?

Please [edit] the question and post the hardware specifications, namely the graphics card.
